# Long xtype analog

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to use long notation of item type instead of xtype.
Can I use

```
{
  title: 'Home',
  iconCls: 'home',
  type: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  store: homeMenuStore,
  itemTpl: homeMenuTpl,
  flex: 1
}
```

instead of

```
{
  title: 'Home',
  iconCls: 'home',
  xtype: 'dataview',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  store: homeMenuStore,
  itemTpl: homeMenuTpl,
  flex: 1
}
```

Comment: why you want to make it typical when there is smarter way already............?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `xclass`:

```
{
    xclass: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use long notation you would do like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
    title: 'Home',
    iconCls: 'home',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    store: homeMenuStore,
    itemTpl: homeMenuTpl,
    flex: 1
});
```

or you can create your own class and extend DataView:

```
Ext.define('myOwnDataview', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    config: {
         title: 'Home',
         iconCls: 'home',
         tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
         store: homeMenuStore,
         itemTpl: homeMenuTpl,
         flex: 1 
    }
});
```